# SSH to remote server using ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm using ansible to automate some tasks. One of those requires me to ssh to server A, then to B from A and then to C from B. I can't seem to find any way to get ansible to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hare you already read articles how to Ansible handles bastion/jump hosts? If so, have you tried using that?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this. I've got it all set up now.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question for other users :)

Comment: Yes, please post an answer on what you were able to set up so that other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 17):

Given that you do not use Paramiko for ssh ([`transport = ssh`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-transport)), Ansible will fully use your `~/.ssh/config`. Therefore you can globally define all connection rules in your ssh configuration.

If for some reason you want Ansible to not use your default ssh config but provide an separate configuration, you can define this in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -F "/path/to/ssh/config/specifically/for/ansible"
```

In your ssh config then set up the connection rules. To stick with your example:

```
Host HostA
  HostName real-host-name-A.com

Host HostB
  HostName real-host-name-B.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -q HostA nc %h %p

Host HostC
  HostName real-host-name-C.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -q HostB nc %h %p
```

- Connections to A are direct
- Connections to B go through A
- Connections to C go through B, which goes through A

Answer (score 5):

For Ansible 2.0 and above you can do the following:

Step #1: Edit the `hosts` file and add a line for your target host:

```
my-target-host ansible_host=10.10.105.23 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/private_key  ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q my-jump-node"'
```

*Notice the use of the `ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q my-jump-node"'` which handles the proxying through the jump node.*

Step #2: In the `~/.ssh/config` file define your `my-jump-node`:

```
Host my-jump-node
  Hostname <IP_ADDRESS>
  User ubuntu
  Port 22
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/nhc-moho/id_rsa # <<< Local path of private key
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/ansible-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 5m
```

Step #3: Notice in step #1 above we have `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/private_key`. This is the private_key stored at the `my-jump-node` and it's corresponding public key is stored at `my-target-host`.

The important thing to remember here is:

> ***YOU HAVE TO COPY THIS PRIVATE KEY FROM THE my-jump-node MACHINE TO YOUR LOCAL MACHINE WHERE YOU RUN ANSIBLE, OR ELSE IT WILL FAIL TO CONNECT TO my-target-host***

Step #4: Test it.

```
ansible my-target-host -m shell -a "echo 'TESTING'"
```