# How to use ansible under a proxy machine

Tags: ansible

we use proxy machine in accessing the production servers. However, i can not get around proxy machine using ssh proxy.

So, can someone tell me how to do ssh proxy configuration when used with ansible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH to remote server using ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661414/ssh-to-remote-server-using-ansible)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there should be no difference in setting up the proxy with or without ansible. You can set the SSH proxy in the .ssh/config file with ProxyCommand and run the ansible commands which should honour your proxy setting.

Comment: Just came across this thread, which discuss similar scenario https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/PdJmnVMhHn0

Comment: Exactly, I do this as well. If Ansible uses OpenSSH and not Paramiko it will use your `~/.ssh/config` and all configured settings including `ProxyComand`.