# How to programmatically download data to AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

There are 3 machines involved in my task

- `A`: my desktop
- `B`: EC2 instance spun up by `A`
- `C`: a remote linux server where data sits and I only have read privilege

The task has basically 3 steps

1. spin up `B` from `A`
2. download data from `C` to `B` to a specific location
3. change some of the downloaded data on `B`

I know how to do 1 using awscli or boto3. Steps 2 and 3 are easy if I ssh to the EC2 instance manually. The problem is that if this task needs to be automated, how can I deal with the login credentials.

Specifically, I am thinking of using `user_data` to run shell scripts after the EC2 instance is born, but the data download uses `scp` which needs password. Then I could upload an ssh credential file to the EC2 instance, but then I cannot utilize `user_data` to run the script for step 2 and 3.

So my current solution is all from shell script

1. spin up `B` from `A`
2. upload ssh credential from `A` to `B`
3. ssh from `A` to `B` with shell commands attached where steps 2 and 3 for the task are performed

This solution appears really ugly to me. Is there a better practice in this case?

Comment: Have you tried ec2-roles on B ?

Comment: Would ec2-roles work if `C` is not an aws instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) it can help you to automate  this task by creating a [playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks.html)

For creating an instance you could use the [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_module.html#examples), from the doc examples:

```
# Basic provisioning example
- ec2:
    key_name: mykey
    instance_type: t2.micro
    image: ami-123456
    wait: yes
    group: webserver
    count: 3
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
    assign_public_ip: yes
```

To download data, the [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/get_url_module.html#examples) module, example:

```
- name: Download file with check (md5)
  get_url:
    url: http://example.com/path/file.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    checksum: md5:66dffb5228a211e61d6d7ef4a86f5758
```

For [modifying files](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modifying-files/modifying-files/) there are multiple modules that can be found in the http://docs.ansible.com/.

In overall is a tool that can help to automate many things, but some time is required to get the basis, check the [Getting started guide](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_getting_started.html), hope it can help.

Comment: What if I need to use scp to download data from server `C`? How is password or key handled?

Comment: The same principle of a bastion host could be used, check this article https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/, also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28258709/1135424

Answer (score 1):

3 Options

1. Pass the encrypted/encoded password as part of userdata. The userdata script will first decrypt/decode the password and use it to `scp` the file from C. Then delete the userdata or someway to delete the encrypted/encoded password
2. Use ssh key instead of ssh password. But the risk is you have to pass the private key in the userdata. Not a secure way.
3. Use Ansible and ssh key. But too much work for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to solve your task. I will not say about task 1 (spin up B from A) because you already done on it. 
**Option 1**: Use [EC2 Run command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/) to push commands to server `B`. Flow: `A -> EC2 Run Command service -> B -> C` No need to push credential (SSH key/password) to server `B`
**Option 2**: Define all you commands in bash shell file, push this shell file to S3. Use `User Data` of server `B` to download that file from S3. Flow: `A -> S3. B get file from S3. B -> C`
With above 2 options, you do not need to push any credentials to server `B`. Server `C` can be any where you have connection between `B` to `C` for downloading task.

Comment: I don't understand why Option 1 and 2 can exempt me from pushing crendetials to `B`. The credential is needed when `B` gets data from `C`. Supposed the shell scripts `B` runs has ssh, how do Option 1 and 2 get round providing credentials?

Comment: So sorry, Im miss understanding  about your credential is necessary for access `C`. If so, why do not you use `A` access to `C` and download to `A` because `A` has credential already? Then, `A` copy to `B` and do other tasks

Comment: I need to download something very big and it'll be a waste to do this transfer twice.